# SQL UPDATE add to field with MIN/MAX

Tags: sql, max

I have this statement

```
UPDATE table SET health = health + 1 WHERE name='Tom'
```

How can I set a MAX for the number field in the statement based off? Pseudo code:

```
UPDATE table set health = min(health+1, max_health) WHERE name='Tom'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to modify the `where`:

```
UPDATE table
    SET health = health + 1
    WHERE name = 'Tom' AND health < max_health;
```

Some databases support the `least()` function:

```
UPDATE table
    SET health = LEAST(health + 1, max_health)
    WHERE name = 'Tom' ;
```

You can also do this using `CASE`.

However, I think the first method is the simplest.

Comment: Thanks, I used the LEAST code. Will select as correct answer when I'm able

Comment: Note that if some records potentially have health > max_health, the first statement won't be equivalent to the pseudocode in the question. (Kind of obvious, I guess, but figured the assumption should be stated.)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `CASE` also

```
UPDATE table 
SET health = (CASE WHEN health+1 < max_health THEN 
                  health+1 
              ELSE 
                  max_health 
              END) WHERE name='Tom'
```

**AND** `IIF` `--SQL Server`

```
UPDATE table SET health = IIF (health+1 < max_health, health+1, max_health) WHERE name='Tom'
```

Comment: What about when `health + 1 = max_health`?

Comment: Then `ELSE` condition which is `max_health` in that situation both `health+1` and `max_health` will be equal so it doesn't impact.

Comment: Well try it out with `health` as 5 and `max_health` as 6.

Comment: Sorry sir, if I am not getting you well but its the fact of conditions but still I tried to keep your words. In such case it goes to the `ELSE` condition. You can check by keeping `6+1` or `7` in place of `max_health` in `ELSE` part and it will return `7`.